# Swift casting using a Warpriest's Fervor, while two-weapon fighting

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, actions, two-weapon-fighting

I am looking at creating a TWF Warpriest for an upcoming campaign and was wondering how the action economy works if I am wielding two kukris but then want to swift cast using Fervor. Am I going to need to have Quick Draw in order to put one weapon away and then redraw it so I have an empty hand for, say, swift casting divine favor, or can I swift cast with both kukris in hand? It would just be a bummer to have to wait until 3rd level to have to pick up Quick Draw due to the 3/4 BAB.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Take the [tour].  The feat [Quick Draw](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/quick-draw-combat---final) doesn't allow a creature also to quick sheathe; it takes a [move action that provokes attacks of opportunity to sheathe a weapon](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Draw-or-Sheathe-a-Weapon) unless using [third party material](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/3rd-party-feats/flaming-crab-games/combat-feats---3rd-party---flaming-crab-games/quick-sheath-combat). Thank you for participating and have fun.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## The [warpriest](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/hybrid-classes/warpriest)'s [fervor](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/hybrid-classes/warpriest#TOC-Fervor-Su-) makes this a snap

Using [fervor](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/hybrid-classes/warpriest#TOC-Fervor-Su-) to cast with your hands full shouldn't be an issue:

> Spells cast in this way [i.e. using the [warpriest](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/hybrid-classes/warpriest)'s [fervor](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/hybrid-classes/warpriest#TOC-Fervor-Su-)] ignore somatic components and do not provoke attacks of opportunity. The warpriest does not need to have a free hand to cast a spell in this way.

So dual-wield those kukris and use your powers for good or for awesome.

Comment: I should learn to read more closely apparently...

Comment: @cstevens Don't worry about it. The quoted text *is* buried at the end of the ability's description. ([And, honestly, I've totally done the same thing.](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/51562/8610) )