# Is it possible to apply Empower Spell to Dispel Magic?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells, metamagic

The Empower Spell feat reads:

> All variable, numeric effects of an empowered spell are increased by
>   one-half. An empowered spell deals half again as much damage as
>   normal, cures half again as many hit points, affects half again as
>   many targets, and so forth, as appropriate. *PHB, p. 93*

Does this also apply to the dispel check of Dispel Magic?

> dispel check (1d20 + your caster level, maximum +10), PHB, p. 223

And if, does this raise the ceiling of maximum +10 for the caster level?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## No

The feat [Empower Spell](http://dndsrd.net/featsList.html#empower-spell) (*Player's Handbook* 93), in part, says

> Saving throws and opposed rolls (such as the one you make when you cast *dispel magic*) are not affected, nor are spells without random variables.

This example is absent from the *SRD*'s feat's benefit.

Comment: Now, that is a bit embarrassing. I think I delete the question.

Comment: @Giorin Don't worry about it. I had a longtime player—who's been playing since *3e*'s release—call me once to ask the same question. I said, "Read the feat." He said, "I did and…." I said, "No, *really*, you think you *know* the feat; now *actually* read it." There was a pause and then he said, "O. Never mind." In other words, it's a *really* easy detail to overlook. `:-)` (Also, from time to time, [we all publicly ask obvious questions.](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/51562/8610))